# Stata: Generate all possible pairs of elements in a list

Tags: combinations, stata

I have a list of elements as a macro, and I would like to generate a macro that contains all possible pairs of these elements, separated by an ampersand. For example, with three elements `az`, `by` and `cx`:

```
local elementList az by cx
```

I would like to dynamically generate a macro pairList containing:

```
az&by az&cx by&cx
```

(The order of the two elements within a pair should not matter, so that either az&by or by&az should be in `pairList` but not both.)

It sounds fairly simple but I'm not sure how to do it elegantly. (In my case I have around ten elements to start with.)

Comment: See also `tuples` from SSC. In Stata, `ssc desc tuples` is how to start.

Comment: Thank you Nick, I'm afraid I do not have access to "external" packages from my machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with Nick's recommendation of `tuples` for this task. The example below suggests a slightly more elegant version of the approach you gave.

```
local elementList a b c d e f g h i j k l

local pairList // initialize the list of pairs
local seenList // initialize the list of elements already seen

foreach first of local elementList {
    foreach second of local seenList {
        local pairList `pairList' `second'&`first'
    } 
    local seenList `seenList' `first'
} 
display "List of unique pairs: `pairList'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure how to use a recursive algorithm like I found on other S.O. threads, so here is my "brute force" approach. Definitely not the most elegant but does th the job:

```
local elementList a b c d e f g h i j k l

local pairList // initialize the list of pairs

foreach first in `elementList' {
    foreach second in `elementList' {
        // only do something if the elements are not the same
        if("`first'" != "`second'") { 
            local pair         `first'&`second'    // pair
            local pairReverse  `second'&`first'    // pair in reverse order

            // if pair (or its inverse) is not already in the list, add the pair
            if(strpos("`pairList'","`pair'") == 0 & strpos("`pairList'","`pairReverse'") == 0 ) { 
                local pairList `pairList' `pair'
            }
        } 
    }   // end of loop on second element
} // end of loop on first element
display "List of unique pairs: `pairList'"
```